# 128gb SSD turned into 1gb after a shut down

Tags: ssd

and bad news...
My 5 years 128 gb Samsung ssd turned into 1gb after a shut down.The drive was in a dell laptop.the specs of the ssd are:
Samsung 2.5" 128 ssd (SATA6.0Gbps)
Model MZ-7PC1280/0L1
F/W CXM04L1Q

The bios see it now as :IDE0 SAMSUNG SATA SSD
IDE0 Serial NUmber :000000000000000 
I plugged the drive into a usb 2.0 enclosure and win 10 saw it as a Unknown 1gb Not initialized 1gb Unalocated drive....I tried to initialize but it gives me that error "Data error (cyclic redudancy check)"

What should i do ?
I own an identical ssd in another laptop.Many thanks

Comment: Back up ,sounds right for you....   you dont sound too professional

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, yes, you should back up. The drive seems toast.

If you need the data, recovery is probably possible to some extent, but tends to be neither easy nor cheap. More so on SSDs than HDDs.